# Can I ask questions about finding specific contents in a book?

Tags: support

I have this electronics book. I never read it since its like a college text book. But I am holding onto this book anyway since I know there might be knowledge that I want somewhere in there. But if it is not there I must look to other resources.

So in effect I am trying to reach out to people who have read this book, and, expecting them to guide me to the content I am interested in...so I can just dive in.

Is this a good place to do this?

Answer (score 5):

No, such a question would be considered off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). You can maybe ask it in the Electrical Engineering chat.

> I know there might be knowledge that I want somewhere in there

Whatever the book, the *Table of contents* and the *Index* are the primary sources to see if there is knowledge that one wants or needs. Use those to find topics of interest and read at least those sections and paragraphs: books need not be read front to back to be useful!